# performance issue between different versions of openmp / gcc compilers

Tags: gcc, centos, load, openmp, cpu

I have some performance issue between different versions of openmp / gcc compilers.

For some reason I encounter some load performance issue while running on M5 Redhat 8.5 Operating System.

I used to run (compile) my application on standard Centos 7.6 O.S
while using Centos 7.6 everything looks OK.
I recently moved from Centos 7.6 (gcc 4.8.5 with OpenMP 201107) to RHL 8.5 (gcc 8.5 with OpenMP 201511).
Since then I have some issues with the load performance.

I also tried to upgrade in the RHL the gcc compiler (from 8.5 to 11.3) which helped a little but did not solve the main problem.

No code changes were made in my application when moving from Centos to RHL

1. Results while working on Centos 7.6:

   - While running (only running the executable without injecting data to the application) - ~2% CPU load
   - While running and injecting data to the application (compiled with openmp)  - ~47% CPU load (and able to process about 90% of the data injected).
   - While running and injecting data to the application (compiled without openmp)  - ~9% CPU load (and able to process about 50% of the data injected).
2. Results while working on RHL 8.5 (original compiler):

   - While running (only running the executable without injecting data to the application) - ~25% CPU load
   - While running and injecting data to the application (compiled with openmp)  - ~97% CPU load (and able to process about 80% of the data injected).
   - While running and injecting data to the application (compiled without openmp)  - ~9% CPU load (and able to process about 50% of the data injected).
3. Results while working on RHL 8.5 (Updated compiler):

   - While running (only running the executable without injecting data to the application) - ~2% CPU load (same as in centos)
   - While running and injecting data to the application (compiled with openmp)  - ~70% CPU load (and able to process about 85% of the data injected).
   - While running and injecting data to the application (compiled without openmp)  - ~9% CPU load (and able to process about 53% of the data injected).

I was wondering what could be the reason for the different behavior with the same code?

Any idea on how to debug this issue will be thankful.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean when you say your program is only able to process some fraction of the data "injected"?  Is there some real-time requirement so old data gets dropped?  What hardware?

Comment: I'm don't really understand your figures of merit. What are those -xx% CPU load? What is your reference? How do you measure them? What would some plain old elapsed time give instead?

Comment: @Gilles I measure CPU load with top (basic Linux app) on different terminal on the Linux box

Comment: @PeterCordes yes this is a real time application, data older then 100ms  is getting dropped, I am running on Lenovo x3550 m5 with 2 CPU's

Comment: To be able to compare them directly, I would try to also build the old gcc (e.g. using [spack](https://spack.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)). Then I would try to find out the difference by profiling the two binaries created by old and new gcc. Without further information you probably wont get any answer here. It might be helpful to know explicitly which compiler version introduced the regression, but building many different versions of gcc seems over the top. Maybe one could use container images of different Linux distributions/versions which ship with different versions of gcc...

Comment: @paleonix: Or find the difference in asm, and then look for it in https://godbolt.org/ which has many GCC versions installed.  But different distros have different defaults for stuff like `-fstack-protector-strong`; IDK if any change in those defaults could matter.

Comment: @PeterCordes right, for some reason I did not think of Compiler Explorer. Getting a bigger project with dependencies to compile on godbolt.com might be a hassle, but I agree that it is the better methodology.

Comment: @paleonix: Right, that's why you'd want to reduce it to a [mcve] of just the part where a difference in the compiler-generated asm makes the key difference, so it's small enough to look at on Godbolt.  (If it's that, rather than some quirk of alignment, or in external libraries like OpenMP thread scheduling / work-allocation defaults.)